# POST request in react hook form not fetching the user input

Tags: reactjs, request, fetch, fetch-api

I am working on an address book and I have fetched all the data from this API url:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

The API cannot really be modified, but it should behave "like if" according to this message in the documentation: "resource will not be really updated on the server but it will be faked as if."

I have set up the react hook form but when I submit my form this is what I get in the dev tools tab network? Shouldn't be showing the user inputs at this point instead of empty string for all fields? The id is the only thing that gets updated.
Is there anything wrong with my Submit function or the actual fetch? Is it ok I have the POST fetch in this component where I have my form as well or should be in the same component where I have the GET request?

[image]

[image]

Would this one be a good way to approach the POST request?

```
const NewUserForm = () => {
     
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
     
  const onSubmit = () => {

    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id:'',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        address1:'',
        address2:'',
        city:'',
        phone:''    
      }),
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json)); 
  }
  
    return (
      <>
        <Header>New user</Header>
          <FormContainer>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>      
              <input type="text" placeholder="name"  {...register("name", { required: true })} />
              {errors.name && <span>This field is required</span>}

              <input type="text" placeholder="email" {...register("email", { required: true })} />
              {errors.email && <span>This field is required</span>}

              <input type="text" placeholder="address1"{...register("address1", { required: true })} />
              {errors.address1 && <span>This field is required</span>}

              <input type="text" placeholder="address2"{...register("address2", { required: true })} />
              {errors.address2 && <span>This field is required</span>}

              <input type="text" placeholder="city"{...register("city", { required: true })} />
              {errors.city && <span>This field is required</span>}
              
              <input type="text" placeholder="phone"{...register("phone", { required: true })} />
              {errors.phone && <span>This field is required</span>}
              
              <input type="submit" />
            </Form>
          </FormContainer>
      </>  
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after checking the react-hook-form docs, here is a possible solution:

In the docs, it says that your onSubmit will have a data param:

```
  const onSubmit = (data) => alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Which means that you can use that in your onSubmit too.
Try changing your onSubmit to use the data parameter:

```
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
```

And revert the change I suggested earlier regarding `handleSubmit`. This is correct:

```
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

Comment: I dont get any response at all with this solution. :/

Comment: Would you be able to post the contents of your `handleSubmit` and/or `register` functions?

Comment: Where do I find that? sorry

Comment: Ah I see, you are using react-hook-form useForm custom hook.

For reference for further commenters: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/

Comment: Not sure if I get your question, but the values dont change as I mentioned in the post. When I enter input and click "submit" it shows empty strings. SHould I send screenshot of something?

Comment: Where in my code should I add the useForm function? It is my first time using React hook form.

Comment: You're already using the useForm hook 
`const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();`

Comment: Yeah, but I dont understand what you are suggesting me to do. Sorry, can you be more especific?

Comment: Oh sorry Dannuzak, I made an edit to my initial answer. Did you get a chance to try that out?

Comment: It woooorks! Thank youuuu!!!

Comment: useForm gives you the `handleSubmit` function which I think sorts out the validations and formatting of your form for you. 
The issue really was that you were passing your data manually: `{id:'', name: '', email: '',}` when you should have been using the `data` parameter in your `onSubmit` function.

Comment: Thank you! you are so kind, i really needed to solve  and understand this and you helped me so quick.